# Unable to find #include "SDL.h"

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, sdl

I have been compiling a code given by Lazy Foo tutorials n after building up, its showing:-

> Fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'SDL.h': No such file or directory

What should I do next? I have followed the procedure given by the tutorials and I don't think I have missed anything.

Answer (score 6):

Go to `http://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php` and scroll down to "Development Libraries". Get the one needed by you, in this case, you need SDL for Windows i suppose? and place it in your lib of Visual Studio.

Comment: I have downloaded it but how am I supposed to put it in the lib section. Acc. to Foo tutorials, I went to configuration properties and included the SDL lib but that isn't helping...

Comment: The file that you downloaded from the link should be a SDL.h file. Check where you Visual Studio folder is, for exmaple c:/Program Files/Visual Studio 2010/lib/ and place the file in the lib folder. Then include sdl.h.

Comment: NOW ITS SHOWING THAT- 

main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init referenced in function _SDL_main
MSVCRT.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
c:\users\sp singh\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\SDL_tutorial\Debug\SDL_tutorial.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals   HOW SHOULD I LINK AGAINST SDL IN THE LINKER

Answer (score 6):

Old thread, but for those who continue to run into this; when you're setting the VC++ Directories, I'm betting the Configuration dropdown at the top of the window was set to "Debug" (That's what happened to me). Change it to "Release" and then add the paths again...